# How do I make separate folder for storing each uploaded file in php?

Tags: php, crud

I have added file upload functionality in my php CRUD project. Each and every time a user uploads file it should get saved in a new folder named as users id so that i can differentiate between them. That new folder should get created in a main folder named 'images' whenever a file is uploaded.

My code for the same is:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {   
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $loginId = $_SESSION['id'];
    $pname = rand(1000,10000)."-".$_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
    $tname = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];  
$uploads_dir= 'C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\crud_html\images'; #this is the path of already created main folder 'images'
    $newd = mkdir($uploads_dir, $id);

    
    move_uploaded_file($tname, $newd.'/'.$pname);
```

But I get following error:

```
Warning: Undefined variable $id in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\crud_html\add.php on line 27

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\crud_html\add.php on line 27

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/8037-bird1.jpg): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\crud_html\add.php on line 30

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "C:\xampp\tmp\php36F9.tmp" to "/8037-bird1.jpg" in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\crud_html\add.php on line 30
```

Note : my images folder is where my add.php file is there.

Please help!!

Comment: Where do you set `$id`? Also, second parameter to `mkdir()` should be the mode and not any id.

Comment: `Each and every time a user uploads file it should get saved in a new folder named as users id`...that doesn't make sense. If the same user can repeatedly upload files, then clearly the second time they do that, you need to re-use the existing folder you already created for them, not create a new one (which you won't be able to to do anyway, because a folder with the same name will already exist). Have another think about your logic.

Comment: As @ADyson mentioned your logic doesnt make sense if one user uploads multiple files. Consider your logic again. Secondly what is `$id` and where are you setting it?

Comment: @ADyson I got your point. In this project I have also added registration option. I can create a folder for file upload when a user registers. After that whenever the user uploads files it will be saved in that folder.